# CreateSymbolicLink on windows 10

Tags: winapi, symlink

ever since they were first introduced, creating a symbolic link required a full administrator. Running from a normal or from a non-elevated process CreateSymbolicLink would fail.

In windows 10, CreateSymbolicLink fails as well in these circumstances, that is it doesn't create anything, however it returns a success code (!) and GetLastError is 0 too. So there's no way to detect the error other than checking if the symlink file exists

Looks like a bug in windows 10?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. But your code could be wrong. We cannot see it.

Comment: I can't reproduce (preview build 10547).

Answer (score 1):

Have experienced the same.
But: The success code you seem to get is an error code. So it seems the have changed the return type of CreateSymbolicLink from BOOLEAN to int

Comment: Ouch; if so, that's definitely a Windows bug.  It would be an easy one for Microsoft to have overlooked: pretty much nobody ever uses that function. :-)

Comment: I see you posted a bug report in the official MSDN documentation page... let's hope somebody will take notice!

Comment: @nikos: I'm guessing that it has already been fixed, since I can't reproduce on the latest preview build (10547).  I don't have a RTM build to test on.  Is anyone who can reproduce the problem able to try upgrading to 10547 to confirm whether or not that resolves it?

Comment: sadly this bug has resurfaced, CreateSymbolicLink returns stuff like -1536 when nothing is created, e.g. because of elevation restrictions. The only way around is to use GetLastError

Answer (score 1):

This workarround works for me:
Change the return value into an integer.

1 = success
for all other values call GetLastWin32Error

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateSymbolicLinkW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
static extern int CreateSymbolicLink(string lpSymlinkFileName, string lpTargetFileName, SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG dwFlags);

public static int CreateSymbolicLinkFix(string lpSymlinkFileName, string lpTargetFileName, int dwFlags) {
    var result = CreateSymbolicLink(lpSymlinkFileName, lpTargetFileName, dwFlags);
    if (result == 1) return 0; // Success
    return Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
}
```